# Matlab Code only Calculating number of pixels and not their sum, if pixel value falls above given Threshold value

Tags: image, matlab

```
K = imread('test.jpg');                               // read image 
countif=0;countelse=0;                                // declare variables
addif=0;addelse=0;
counttotal=0; temp=0;        
[M N] = size(K);                                      // calculate the size of the image
for x=1:M                                             // X-Axis
    for y=1:N                                         // Y-Axis

                temp=K(x,y);                          // Pixel Value at location(x,y)

                if (temp<50)                          // If value of pixel is below threshold value 50 
                    addif =  addif + temp;            // Add to get sum of all these pixels
                    countif = countif + 1;            // Counter to get total number of such pixels 


                else                                  // If pixel value is above threshold limit i.e 50
                 countelse = countelse + 1;           // Add to get sum of all these pixels
                 addelse=   addelse + temp;           // Counter to get total number of such pixels 
                end

        counttotal=counttotal+1;                     // Total rotation counter
    end
end
```

Here in this code, given above, counters named 'countif' and 'countelse' are working properly but values in variables 'addif' and 'addelse' are not as it should be.

Comment: What do you mean by "not as it should be?" I assume `K` is a two-dimensional array?

Comment: K is a two-dimensional. variables addif and addelse is not providing the sum of all variables, which satisfies the condition.

Comment: Yes but what does that mean? Is it too high, too low, 0, NaN? Did you try it on a smaller array where you can observe what happens? e.g. `[1 100 ; 200 2]`

Comment: Yes, i tried. Both variables just give a single value like as [255] or [231]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:-**

Replace this: `K = imread('test.jpg');` with this: `K = double(imread('test.jpg'))` ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Or if you want to keep the `unit8` class of `K` and `temp`, instead of above fix, do the following: ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍Replace this `addif =  addif + temp;`
with this: `addif =  addif + double(temp);` ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍
 ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍and this `addelse= addelse + temp;` with this: `addelse=   addelse + double(temp);`

**Explanation:-**

Class of `temp` is `uint8`, because class of `K` is `uint8` therefore classes of your resulting `addif` and `addelse` also become `unit8` which cannot store value more that `255`.  By converting `K` into `double`, all your next variables using it, become `double` as I did in first proposed solution. Or if you want to keep the classes of `K` and `temp` same, you can use the second proposed solution.

You can check the class of variables by using `whos` in command window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing for this

```
tresholdMask = (K < 50); %array of the same size as k with 1s where K<50 and 0s elsewhere
numOfPixels = sum(thresholdMask(:)); %number of 1s in the mask
sumOfPixels = sum(K(:).*thresholdMask(:)); %sum of all the pixels where the mask is 1
```